# Print duplicated numbers to another file

Tags: linux, shell

is there an easy way to count occurencies of specific numer inside a file? For example, I've got a file numbers.txt containing as follows:

154;459;444;154
   356;2;478;154

I need to print to another file only the numbers that are duplicated, so in file duplicate.txt i should have only one occurency of `154`

Comment: You should add a language and what you tried. It's a common recipe in python (using set or dict) or i perl (using hashes).

Comment: Perhaps uniq -d can help, if you first sort your numbers into separate lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, "[uniq](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) -d", with suitable preprocessing will work:

```
tr ';' '\n' <numbers.txt | sort |uniq -d
```

Steps:

- translate the semicolons to newlines using [tr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr)
- sort the data
- use "uniq -d" to show duplicates.

You should note however, that the newline escape `\n` is not described in [POSIX tr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) (it works with OSX and Linux).